# laravel MVC execution flow

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I am new to laravel framework. I am trying to edit laravel webapplication.

Website is running in EC-2 instance of AWS.
I am doing SCP with filezilla.

I found that /var/www/html/app has one route.php file. 
one of the route defined over there is :

```
#get checkout page
Route::get('/checkout', ['as' => 'checkout', 'uses' => 'CartController@getCheckout']);
```

When I hit example.com/checkout

It moves me to example.com/cart

**getCheckout() of cart controller**

```
// show checkout form
    public function getCheckout()
    {

        if(getCartTotal())
        {

            return View::make('cart.checkout'); 


        }else {

            return Redirect::route('cart')->withCartErrorMessage('Please add some items to cart!');
        }
    }
```

My question is . when i change above route to product page or any thing else. it does not reflects and still moves me to wxample.com/cart.

even I removed route.php file and then hit example.com/checkout , it still moves me to example.com/cart

Why is it so ?

**Edit :**

I tested with php artisan routes command ,it lists all the routes from routes.php , and when i remove route.php file from /var/www/html/app folder, above command says Your application doesn't have any routes.

that means i am editing proper routes.php file. 
But why changed routes in /var/www/html/app routes.php file are not being reflected ?

Comment: you are modifying the wrong file, laravel uses the `app/http/routes.php` file not `app/routes.php`

Comment: there is no app/http folder

Comment: run command `php artisan routes` and find which routes are registered. it could be that there is some caching involved or that there are routes declared in controller using symfony's syntax.

Comment: if you are using laravel 5.1, then command is `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I run above command in putty ,it says : Could not open input file: artisan.

Comment: i see. run that command on your local copy of site. it should work there for sure.

Comment: I run php artisan routes command successfully, now how can i check that which route.php is getting executed in my application ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108780/discussion-between-nirali-joshi-and-raj-kamal).

Comment: change tag from laravel 5 to laravel 4.2 as problematic code is using laravel 4.2

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getCartTotal())
        {

            return View::make('cart.checkout'); 


        }else {

            return Redirect::route('cart')->withCartErrorMessage('Please add some items to cart!');
        }
```

In the above getCartTotal() function is returning false that is why it is redirecting to else and and then goes to cart

Comment: but why checkout/ request goes to CartController@getCheckout ,when i removed route.php file ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the view cache, something similar happened to me before. In the folder storage/frameworks/views, i just cleared them all or by command

```
php artisan view:clear
```